# How to pull in CMD input into custom profile script for Powershell

Tags: powershell

So, I'm trying to write a simple powershell script that will SSH me into one box, and then into another. The logic is:
SSH -J A B

I'm not sure what syntax to use, but is there way to do something like:

```
function name {SSH -J box1 [cmd input]}
```

So that way I can just use the alias "name" and it will SSH into box1 and then into another box that I type into the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function name ($cmd) {SSH -J box1 "$cmd"}
name "whoami"
```

I hope this helps you get the function to run with an arbitrary command. You just need to be careful about escaping special characters.

This doesn't double-hop but I didn't fully understand your use case for that.

Comment: That totally worked. Thank you so much. Ya sorry, I was having a hard time explaining what I wanted it to do. Essentially, we have to remote into a proxy box in order to ssh into our main boxes for work. with the ssh -J command, I was able to bypass having to put in the password all the time, but I was having trouble figuring out how to make it an alias so I don't have to type out the whole thing.

Comment: Glad you're off and running.